# Bulk Insert FROM a table variable

Tags: sql-server

My `c#` application is a performance logging application so we are just stuffing data metrics into a db table.

I have a `User-Defined-Table-Type`.
That type is then used as a parameter in a stored procedure.

The `c#` application gathers data for a period of time then it populates a DataTable and passes that to the sproc.

In the sproc I'm looking for a way to insert rows into a table and NOT do it via `RBAR`. (Row By Agonizing Row)

I mean you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO ExistingTable (Columns,..)
SELECT Columns,...
FROM TableValuedParm
```

But wouldn't that be `RBAR` too?

Is there was a way to do an insert join etc..

Thanks

Comment: That is not RBAR. You are not retrieving or doing anything for each row. You are using a result set as the list of value for your insert statement. That is the correct way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: INSERT doesn't touch any of the existing rows, so it's not RBAR.

Comment: OK Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's the way to do it. Definitely not RBAR, it should be pretty fast.